# MediumBlob in Laravel database schema

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-4

How can I create a `Mediumblob` within the Laravel schema builder ?

In the docs it says :

```
$table->binary('data'); // BLOB equivalent to the table
```

But I need a MediumBlob otherwise the images get truncated at 64K; we are running MySQL.

I know that Laravel's schema builder is DB agnostic, but is there a way to avoid the "native way" and if not how can i create a `Mediumblob` column ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**You can't.**

This [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3544) suggests using raw queries to create such columns, so you should do something like this in your  migration file :

```
Schema::create("<table name>", function($table) {
    // here you do all columns supported by the schema builder
});

// once the table is created use a raw query to ALTER it and add the MEDIUMBLOB
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE <table name> ADD <column name> MEDIUMBLOB");
```

Comment: Have you created the issue? you the number? I could find it

Comment: user2629998 links to an issue

Answer (score -3):

The field is created but the file can not be inserted. And the following error is caused:

`#1118 - Row size too large (> 8126)`

Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` or `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED` may help. In current row format BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.