# Column Types for 64 Encoded Image via Laravel Migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, database-migration

`$table->text('company_logo')->nullable();`

I'm trying to create a migration to store Base 64 Encoded image in my My SQL database. I'm not if what I have is good enough.

Is what I have good enough ? How do I know it ?

Comment: Make it a blob. Also don't store images in a database.

Comment: `$table->binary('data');` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store and retrieve image contents from the database using Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428876/how-to-store-and-retrieve-image-contents-from-the-database-using-laravel)

Comment: @JamesLalor I agree that storing images in a database is in most cases detrimental to performance, since HTTP servers leverage `sendfile` to serve static content very fast. But there are cases where this could be used. For example when using a load balancer, there's the need for replication to sync content across all machines that serve it, and having a dedicated db server which also stores the images negates that need. There are of course pros and cons to this approach, but it can be a legitimate use in some cases.

Comment: @ihue Yes `binary` is the Schema Builder's method for adding a column with type `blob`. However `blob` has a size limit of ~64KB, so if you want to store something larger that that (such as `mediumblob`) there's no method to abstract that so you need to [do that using a raw query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089652/mediumblob-in-laravel-database-schema).

Answer (score 1):

Storing any binary data (including images) in DB is a bad practice. You should save uploaded images as files and store links to them in DB.

Answer (score 0):

its a bad idea to store images in database. it would be better if you save only path to you image in db. when you fetch the post data, you can just decode your base64 image, move this image to your images directory and save only the path to this image in database(for example /img/mypic.jpg)