# Medium Blob or Long Blob support for database Schema builder

Tags: mysql, postgresql, laravel-5, sqlsrv

How to make database migration schema for Medium Blob or Long Blob in Laravel 5.2? We can write some commands like below

```
 \DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `attachment` ADD `file` MEDIUMBLOB');
```

But these commands are just MySQL supported but it does not support for PotgresSQL.

Is there any possibility for a laravel command directly that support for all the database supported by laravel.

Comment: Have you tried? `$table->binary('data');` its BLOB equivalent for the database.

Comment: Binary gets me only blob but not "medium blob" or "long blob"

Comment: I second @sujitprasad. I only got blob. I want long blob. Ever figure this out?

Comment: I haven't figured this out so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MediumBlob in Laravel database schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089652/mediumblob-in-laravel-database-schema)