# Laravel add CLOB column

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, field, clob

Hey I've searched everywhere on google and In Laravel documentation and I couldn't find how can I add CLOB field to the table. Is it possible?

```
$table->clob('test');
```

Isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel's schema manager doesn't support all column types.

Medium and long blobs arent supported so I guess cblob isnt any aswell

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3544

There is a way to do it raw quires DB::statement in a migration.

Take a look at this answer

[MediumBlob in Laravel database schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089652/mediumblob-in-laravel-database-schema)

TL;DR

```
Schema::create("<table name>", function($table) {
    // here you do all columns supported by the schema builder
});

// once the table is created use a raw query to ALTER it and add the MEDIUMBLOB
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE <table name> ADD <column name> MEDIUMBLOB");
```